# How do I change autoformat in vim?

Tags: vim, scripting, format, autoformatting

I use autoformat (textwidth = 72) to write my emails in vim.

The problem is that every time I write a list or short phrases, vim joins it to the line above.

p.e.

```
These are my options:
- option nr. 1
```

When I write "-", the "-" is immediately joined with the phrase above:

```
These are my options: -
```

Same when I use other kind of lists p.e. numbered lists or other symbols before the list.

Same thing when I write phrases shorter then 72 characters p.e.

```
This is my text.
This is my text on the 2nd line.
```

Autoformat changes it to:

```
This is my text. This is my text on the 2nd line.
```

How can I change this behavior?
I only want to format long lines when there are no Carriage Return `<CR>` in the first 72 characters.
If there is a `<CR>` it has to break there.

Comment: so you don't wanna get rid of autoformat but then how is vim supposed to know where you want to break or not?

Comment: I want to break at 72 characters (that is the textwidth I added in vimrc). So If I write a line longer then 72 it has to break at 72 and continue the line below. If I write a line p.e. of 60 characters and push the enter key on my keyboard to go to the line below Vim has to leave the line as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help autoformat` gives some useful hints:

> - You need to properly define paragraphs.  The simplest is paragraphs that are
>     separated by a blank line.  When there is no separating blank line, consider
>     using the 'w' flag and adding a space at the end of each line in the
>     paragraphs except the last one.

So, either `:setlocal fo+=w`, or turn off autoformat (maybe only temporarily, with a quick toggle mapping).

Comment: Ingo, `:help autoformat` --> E149: sorry, no help for autoformat.

Comment: `:help auto-format`; the other tag spelling is apparently only available in the latest runtime updates.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat Still have problems with autoformat. Doesn't autoformat recognize lists set in formatlistpat? These are my settings `let &formatlistpat='^\s*\([-*]\|\d\+[.)]\|\a\+[.)]\)\s\+'` and `set formatoptions=tcqronw`